# WeakReference and Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

I'm trying to understand how `WeakReference` works and why the following snippet of code runs forever, i.e. why the `dummy` string is never GC'd despite seemingly dropping all references to it?

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dummy = new String("sdfsdfsdf");
    WeakReference<String> dummyRef = new WeakReference<>(dummy);

    Thread test = new Thread(
      () -> {
        while (true) {
          try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          }

          String s = dummyRef.get();
          if (s == null) {
            System.out.println("String GC'd. Quitting.");
            break;
          }

          System.out.println(s);
          s = null;
        }
      }
    );
    test.start();

    try {
      dummy = null;
      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

Is the GC actually being run here or is the lambda holding a reference to objects in the surrounding stack frame despite never actually using the `dummy` variable directly? What changes would I have to make to have the code work as expected?

The use case for this is a factory method for a class that will spawn a thread that calls a method of the returned object at a regular interval. I would like the thread to quit if the object created is destroyed (i.e. allow for the object to be GC'd).

Comment: I think the fact that you are initializing your string with a *literal* means it will not get garbage collected until the class is unloaded. You should probably try `String dummy = new String("sdfsdfsdf");` instead.

Comment: I'll fix the code, but this is actually a simplification of a more complex example, where the object was not a string literal and the same problem remains. In other words, not using a string literal doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: I actually tested this. The thing is that if the garbage collector doesn't have to, it won't remove the object. If there is nothing pressuring memory, the reference will be kept. If you add a `System.gc()` to your test, it will definitely work. Or you can simulate that with another thread that allocates a lot of memory (and releases it).

Comment: You're right... Would seem like I would then have to start a thread that calls the GC... Otherwise, I would have to assume that whenever these objects are destroyed the GC would still be run, i.e. that there is enough memory pressure at that stage in the application.

Comment: I don't think you should call `System.gc()` in real production code. If you are forcing garbage collects, then something in your design is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

Your test should work if it included a reason for the garbage collector to be activated. Let's add a thread that just eats memory to it:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dummy = new String("sdfsdfsdf");
    WeakReference<String> dummyRef = new WeakReference<>(dummy);

    // This thread creates arrays and chucks them.
    // Marked as a daemon to ensure it doesn't stop the program
    // from quitting.
    Thread memEater = new Thread(
      () -> {
          for( int i=1;;i++) {
              int[] arr = new int[6553500];
              arr[0] = i;
              try {
                  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              }
          }
      }
    );
    memEater.setDaemon(true);
    memEater.start();

    Thread test = new Thread(
      () -> {
        while (true) {
          try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          }

          String s = dummyRef.get();
          if (s == null) {
            System.out.println("String GC'd. Quitting.");
            break;
          }

          System.out.println(s);
          s = null;
        }
      }
    );
    test.start();

    try {
      dummy = null;
      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

The output I got from this was:

```
% java Test                                                                                                 
sdfsdfsdf
sdfsdfsdf
sdfsdfsdf
sdfsdfsdf
String GC'd. Quitting.
```